# What gcp firewall settings are needed to enable file download for wordpress site backup?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, download, firewall

I recently created a wordpress site using the automatically setup version gcp provides:
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress

The firewall it creates is allows ingress for tcp:80 on IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
Otherwise, I have the default firewalls that gcp creates and applys to all.
All is fine with normal site operation.

I wish to backup/migrate the wordpress site, and attempted to use the All-in-One WP Migration plugin.  However, I get an 'server error' when attempting to download a file from it.  My best guess (and it is a guess) is that firewall rules are not allowing the file transfer.  What firewall settings do I need to allow and/or how do I figure that out?  What are the typical firewall options that get set for downloads?

Alternatively, if I am going down the wrong path for backup/migration of a wordpress site on gcp, please let know.

Thanks!

Comment: The server error is not caused by VPC Firewall rules. Review the WordPress PHP log files for error messages. You might get better answers on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall rule allowing ingress traffic on tcp port 80 from IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 is the right choice for your setup, so the firewall rules might not be the cause of the issue.

I would suggest you to check the following options for troubleshooting -

1. Make sure your plugins are all updated. You can stop/remove the plugins which
   are not in use and download the file with trusted and updated plugins.
2. Ensure that your hypertext access (.htaccess) file is not broken.
3. Check the ‘error.log’ file to find any specific error.

Please refer to following link for details on how to connect to your wordpress site in GCP via FTP - https://onepagezen.com/manage-wordpress-files-on-google-cloud-platform

You can also explore other ways to successfully download your wordpress files in the  following link - https://blogvault.net/how-to-migrate-wordpress-site